# Convert special symbols to corresponding Html Entity Numbers

Tags: php, xml, xsl-fo

I need to convert special characters like `(®¢)` to corresponding HTML entity numbers using PHP.
Is there a function like `htmlentities()` to achieve this functionality? We need to populate the special symbols in an `xsl:fo` document. The best way to do this, is to store the special characters as entity numbers.

Comment: @Neeraj: Those tags had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: What is the goal of this unusual requirement? Why is htmlentities() not sufficient?

Comment: @fabspro: If we use htmlentities, the output is an html entity name like &reg; which is not rendered by an xsl:fo document. Since, we are creating pdf using xsl:fo. We used html entity numbers instead of entity names.. and this worked. But we dont know how to convert a special symbol to corresponding entity number using php.

Comment: Why not just use the right encoding for the document so you don’t need to?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [mb_encode_numericentity](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php).

```
mb_encode_numericentity ($string, array (0x0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8')
```

This will convert the entire string into numeric entities. You can change the ranges of characters that will be converted by modifying the members of the second argument to `mb_encode_numericentity`.

Comment: @vegeta no problem, not sure why you need to do this though... see minitech's comment